# getting a file from outside the document root. PHP

Tags: php, file, document-root

I am currently storing docx files and pdf files in a user upload folder outside the doc root. I intend for these files to be downloaded via a db link to the heavily scrambled file name.

Previously I have only obtained data from files outside the root with PHP - is it possible to retrieve whole files from this area and if so how does one go about it.

Comment: if I had an upload file outside of the doc root how would I use symbolic link to gain access to this. Am I right in understanding that a symbolic link masks the original file path ?

Comment: Yeah... We can say that they *mask* the original file path. But what matters is that they allow you to access a resource without changing the file path. For example, if you create a symbolic link to *~/myfolder* in *~/myproject_root/uploads*, people would be able to access *myfolder* content as if it was really in the project root.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$file_id = $_GET['id'];

$local_path = get_real_filelocation_from_id($file_id);

readfile($local_path);
```

The code for `get_real_filelocation_from_id()` is left as an exercise for the OP.

Comment: you forgot to set the mimetype (see the docs example for readfile)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$get_file=$_GET['file_name'];
$file = '/path/to/uploads/'.$get_file;

if (file_exists($file)) {
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
}
?>
```

After many hours of searching I found this that seems to work. Unfortunately, although the symbolic link root seemed to be a good path to follow I am unsure of how to actually implement it - firebug goes into quirks mode when I try even the most basic script.