# not getting the server root folder path address

Tags: php, centos

the www root folder is in:

```
/var/www/html/testweb
```

documents are in folder:

```
/doc/
```

which is located out of the www folder for public web pages. now i want to get that location but can not on php.

```
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'doc/;
```

it's results

```
/var/www/html/doc/
```

while i want the result to be `/doc/` which is on the root of linux system.

regard

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use `getenv()` which gets the value of an environment variable. I'm assuming HOME goes to your root, check your environment variables if its not HOME, so you know which one to use.

Example:

```
echo getenv("HOME") . '/doc/';
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is outside of your DocumentRoot, use

```
echo '/doc/';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access to the outside of the server's root directory in this way.

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

The document root directory under which the current script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file.

That's answered your question but if you wanna include a file from that directory 
 you can just access the file like so

```
include  "/doc/test.php";
```

You may have a look on this [getting a file from outside the document root. PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398109/getting-a-file-from-outside-the-document-root-php?rq=1)